# Do Symmetric Games with Nash Equilibria always have a symmetric Equilbrium?

Tags: game-theory, symmetry

Define a game with S players to be Symmetric if all players have the same set of options and the payoff of a player depends only on the player's choice and the set of choices of all players.
Equivalently A game is symmetric if applying a permutation to the options chosen by people induces the same permutation on the payoffs. For example if the original set of options chosen were 1,2,1,3 and the pay-offs were 6,0,6,100 respectively then if the game is symmetric the set of options 2,1,1,3 would have to lead to the pay-offs 0,6,6,100

Suppose a Symmetric Game S has at least 1 nash equilbrium, then must S have a symmetric Nash equilbrium i.e. a nash equilbrium where all players use the same strategy? If not under what conditions does there exist a nash equilbrium. If so is there a simple proof or a simple idea behind the proof?

Clearly this doesn't hold if we restrict to pure strategies the game with the following payoff matrix where all pure equilbria are asymmetric serves as a counter example, But I've yet to find a counterexample for impure strategies.

0/0 1/1
 1/1 0/0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes for finite games and for zero-sum games. In general, however, the answer is no: http://www.rochester.edu/college/faculty/markfey/papers/SymmGame3.pdf

Answer (score 7):

The answer is yes for finite games and mixed strategies and this was already shown in the [Ph.D thesis](http://www.princeton.edu/mudd/news/faq/topics/Non-Cooperative_Games_Nash.pdf) of John Nash, where it occurs as Theorem 4. Nash considered actually slightly more invariances in his theorem.

The proof amounts to the verification that one can do the usual fixed-point argument used for the proof that every finite game has a Nash equilibrium in mixed strategies, restricted to the set of symmetric strategy profiles and to symmetric best responses.

Comment: Does the same result hold for infinite symmetric zero-sum games?

Comment: @Governor The game of "who can pick a larger natural number" has no equilibrium.

Comment: What if the strategy space is bounded?

Comment: @Governor What formal result is it you are interested in exactly?

Comment: If I have a symmetric zero-sum game with infinite strategies, say I find a distribution $F$ such that the expected payoff for this distribution is always greater than or equal to $0$. Can I say that it is a Nash equilibrium. The paper: https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2006/RM408.pdf   page 7 in particular where the author shows his proposed solution in Nash Equilibrium. I want to check whether the condition he proves is sufficient.

Comment: @Governor If both players use such strategies, they must be minmax strategies and, therefore,  constitute a NE. But that has little to do with the original question.