# Could there be multiple symmetric equilibriums in a symmetric games?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Given a finite symmetric 2 player game with a strategy space $S$, a (mixed-strategy) symmetric equilibrium is a distribution $d\in \Delta(S)$ such that $(d,d)$ is a Nash equilibrium.

A known result is that in such game there always exists a symmetric equilibrium (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/191726/do-symmetric-games-with-nash-equilibria-always-have-a-symmetric-equilbrium)).

Could there be multiple (extreme) symmetric equilibriums? that is two symmetric equilibriums $d_1,d_2$ such that $d=\frac{d_1+d_2}{2}$ is **not** an equilibrium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Consider the coordination game $(A,B) = (I,I)$, where $I$ is the $n \times n$ identity matrix.

For this game there are $2^{n}-1$ symmetric equilibria of the form $(x,x)$ where $x=(1/|S|,\ldots,1/|S|)$ for non-empty $S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$. I.e., the equilibria comprise all identical uniform mixtures. These are all equilibria.

Comment: Nice, Thanks Rahul  !

Comment: You're welcome.